# mod_rewrite condition not firing?

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, cache-control, clean-urls

Before I redirect the user, I want to check if the redirected-to-file actually exists. Now the following code works yet right when I add the bit which is currently commented out it skips the rewrite rule altogether.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>   
  RewriteEngine on    
  RewriteBase /   
  # RewriteCond cache/$1.html -f      
  RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?([^/]*) cache/$1.html [L]    
<IfModule>
```

Ive been struggling on this for three days now, any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: I don't think $1 is populated at the time the RewriteCond runs.  You probably need to add another RewriteCond before that one to populate $1, or something like that.

Comment: Frank Farmer, if you would provide the additional rule as an answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `# RewriteCond cache/$1.html -f` the `$1` doesn't refer to anything, so it is going to skip your RewriteRule.

Try

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/%{REQUEST_URI}.html -s
```

[RewriteCond Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)

Comment: I'll test this as soon as I get home but I was wondering will your rule need a .html at the end since I'm actually redirecting this exact pattern, `example.com/user` to `example.com/cache/user.html`

Comment: I've tried this, and it doesn't work unfortunately.. I cant tell why. Is there anyway to export where the rules point to, to make a manual check?

Comment: You can enable the [RewriteLog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteLog) to see why it's not working

Answer (score -1):

My first impression is to check that cache/$1.html exists and that you aren't accidentally redirecting from myserver.com/index.html -> to -> myserver.com/cache/index.html.html

Comment: cache/$1.html does exist since the RewriteRule shows the file when I remove the condition, I presume since I've addressed the redirected-to-file identically to the one that is pre-checked in the condition, it should check for the same file... But for some reason, it doesn't find it in the condition, so confusing.